# Call to undefined function pg_pconnect()

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, wamp

Estou precisando criar uma conexão com um banco de dados(já existente) em PostgreSQL(Instalado e funcionando), usando esse código(que também já existia).

## Arquivo acesso_bd.php

```
<?php
    function conecta() {
        $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $acesso = "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=meubanco user=meuuser password=minhasenha port=5432";
        $bd = pg_pconnect($acesso);
        return $bd;
    }
```

No meu arquivo `index.php` eu chamo esse arquivo e juntamente o método `conecta`, ele mostra a mensagem `Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_pconnect()`.

## Procedimentos Realizados

Eu acessei o php.ini(da pasta do PHP) e tirei como comentário a linha `extension= php_pgsql.dll`, verifiquei também que o arquivo php_pgsql.dll está na pasta referenciada ppelo extension_dir - `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/"`. Copiei o arquivo `php_pgsql.dll` para a pasta `apache\bin`. A

### Alteração httpd.conf

Adicionada a linha, conforme indicada pelo Anthony Accioly.
    LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/libpq.dll"

### Mensagem de Erro

#### index.php

```
Warning: pg_connect(): in C:\wamp\www\testebd\acesso_bd.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  237520  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0010  241064  conecta( )  ..\index.php:3
3   0.0010  241248  pg_connect ( )  ..\acesso_bd.php:8
```

Essa `acesso_bd.php:8` é `$bd = pg_pconnect($acesso);` e `index.php:3` é `$dadosConexao = conecta();`.

#### phpinfo()

```
pdo_pgsql

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.2
Module version  1.0.2
Revision    $Id$

pgsql

PostgreSQL Support |enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.2.2
PostgreSQL(libpq)   Uninitialized version string (win32)
Multibyte character support enabled
SSL support disabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0

Directive |Local Value | Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent  On  On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent Off Off
pgsql.ignore_notice Off Off
pgsql.log_notice    Off Off
pgsql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
```

Comment: Você chegou a restartar o servidor após descomentar a linha? Outra coisa, se estiver rodando o PHP como módulo copie o `php_pgsql.dll` para a pasta `apache\bin`(veja http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438059/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-pg-connect (em inglês))

Comment: Poste as entradas relevantes do `phpinfo()`. Veja também se abrir o arquivo `libpq.dll` (no `[diretório de instalação do seu PostgreSQL]\bin\libpq.dll`) ajuda. Exemplo, no `httpd.conf` incluir a linha `LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/libpq.dll"` (fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551734/php-not-loading-php-pgsql-dll-on-windows (em inglês)).

Comment: Parece que o wamp também vem com o `libpq.dll` em `bin\php\php5.5.12\libpq.dll` (se você não tiver o PHP instalado localmente).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Que parte do phpinfo() devo copiar ?

Comment: Todas as linhas relacionadas com módulos do PostgreSQL (e seu warning também, acho que você cortou ele no meio).

Comment: É obrigatório que seja `pg_pconnect`, não pode ser `pg_connect`? Na documentação do PHP tem algumas notas, onde  a primeira diz que algumas funções pode não funcionar em algumas compilações... [Notas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pgsql.php). Tente a `pg_connect`.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Estou utilizando o `pg_pconnect` pois é o script padrão que o pessoal da empresa costuma usar, mas eu troquei-o por `pg_connect` e o erro permaneceu o mesmo.

Comment: Alan, ainda está faltando alguma coisa nesse seu Warning (tipo um `Unable to connect 
to PostgreSQL server` ou algo do gênero). Aparentemente o driver está funcionando como deveria agora, é só questão de ver o que está te impedindo de conectar (se é a String de conexão ou alguma parametrização de segurança do PostgreSQL).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/606x250q90/743/7RqZMI.jpg

Comment: Não tem nada mais no log navegando para `pg_connect`? Tenta abrir a torneira de erros do php também (commandos aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/664577).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly deixei meu index.php assim: 

`require_once('acesso_bd.php');
$dadosConexao = conecta();
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

A mensagem não mudou em nada.

Comment: Poe os comandos dentro do `acesso_bd`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Coloquei depois do return. Deu na mesma :(.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17461/discussion-between-anthony-accioly-and-allan-ramos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversei com o responsável que me passou o código,vai lá saber, mas mudaram a porta para: `port=5433`